# Check SkuDetails subscription billing frequency

Tags: android, google-play-console, billingclient

In Android development with Google Billing, how do I get the billing frequency for a `Subscription`

`SkuDetails.subscriptionPeriod()` returns a date string. Is there a way to get the billing frequency for example `monthly` or `yearly` or am I going to have to just cleverly code this to match what I have in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrong to assume truth from searching through other posts. I have debugged and found out that:

`SkuDetails.subscriptionPeriod()` returns something like P1Y, or P1M, or whatever else as a string.

- **P1M**: Per 1 Month
- **P1Y**: Per 1 Year
- etc depending on what subscription frequency you have set up

I am now using those abbreviations for reference.